# How to exclude index from query

Tags: sql-server

I recently added an index to a table with about 20 million rows to improve performance for some queries. That worked well. The problem is that once a day, several statistics are generated and now, with that index, one of the queries is now taking too long (from a couple minutes to timing out after 30 minutes).

I looked at the table hints and only saw how to specify use of an index and not how to exclude use of an index. Did I miss something? Is there a way to force an index to not be used by the execution plan? I'd prefer to keep the index but will remove it if there is no way to exclude it on the nightly statistics generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do

```
SELECT *
FROM [Table] WITH (INDEX(0))
WHERE "IndexColumn" = 0
```

tablescan will be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know without seeing a query, but it sounds like a case where the following may help:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (INDEX(0))
WHERE MyColumn = 'MyValue'
```

If that doesn't work for you, then you may need to post some additional information on what your query contains.